# При нажатии в ListBox поставить галочку CheckBox

Tags: wpf

Как забиндить ListCheckBox в WPF? Ситуация такая что ширина чекбокса равна длине текста в нем (меньше чем ListBox, и соответственно чтобы сработал Checked нужно навести на текст и клацнуть (сделал костыли увеличил ширину чекбокса до ширины listbox). Но хотелось бы забиндить их, а не использовать костыль.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox_products" Width="200" Height="300" Background="DarkGray" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding GetAvailProductsOnProject}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox_CheckProduks" Width="300" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Продукт}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Если какой-то из ответов помог вам, отметьте его галочкой (она слева под кнопками для голосования)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем тут несколько. Во-первых, вам нужно растянуть ячейку на всю ширину. Во-вторых, вам нужно, чтобы контент вашего checkbox'а не выходил за правую границу.

Для этого делаем так:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox_products" Width="200" Height="300"
         Background="DarkGray" Margin="5,5,5,5"
         ItemsSource="{Binding GetAvailProductsOnProject}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Продукт}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: простая анимашка по имени Наташка]

Comment: А как допустим вне лист бокса сделать(Снизу допустим), чекбокс который бы при чекед в лист боксе бы сделал все значения чекед и наоборот не чекед.

Comment: @LaNC1LoT: Это уже новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно. В две строчки ответить не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Все элементы, помещенные в ListBox, оборачиваются в ListBoxItem, поэтому вам нужно растянуть именно ListBoxItem`ы. Сделать это можно так:

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Ширину CheckBox устанавливать явно при этом не нужно, уберите установку Width из разметки. CheckBox будет растянут на всю ширину контейнера (ListBoxItem) и, соответственно, на всю ширину ListBox.